# is there any way get each item of list without using for loop?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

is there any way get each item of list without using for loop ?

i.e. Given data

```
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+
|  id|     date|   revenue   |con_dist_1| con_dist_2|
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|
|3310|1/15/2018|   0.01378215|         4|0.082049528|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|
|3310|1/15/2018|   0.01378215|         4|0.082049528|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.014933087|         5|0.034681906|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.014448282|         3|0.082049528|
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+

val col_list = Array("con_dist_1","con_dist_2")

val median_col_list = partitioned_data.stat.approxQuantile(col_list, Array(0.0,0.1,0.5),0.0)


val percentile_0 = 0;
val percentile_10 = 1;


val Q0 = median_col_list(col_list.indexOf("con_dist_1"))(percentile_0)
val Q10 =median_col_list(col_list.indexOf("con_dist_1"))(percentile_10)
```

> Without looping col_list , is there any way calculate percentile_0 &
>   percentile_10 for each item in col_list , i mean parallelly ...using
>   map or something ???

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: use `percentile_approx` with groupBy or Window to keep the other columns

Answer (score 1):

I will answer "how do you calculate multiple (approximate) percentiles in one pass, for multiple columns"?

According to [DataFrameStatFunctions docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions), the signature

```
approxQuantile(cols: Array[String], probabilities: Array[Double], relativeError: Double): Array[Array[Double]]
```

has been available (only) since 2.2.0.

If you're using an older version of Spark, it won't have this signature, and it won't be as easy to do this computation.

This is an example from your data, using Spark 2.4.0.

```scala
val df = Seq((3310,"1/15/2018",0.010680705,6,0.019875458),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.006628853,4,0.816039063),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.01378215,4,0.082049528),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.010680705,6,0.019875458),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.006628853,4,0.816039063),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.01378215,4,0.082049528),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.010680705,6,0.019875458),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.010680705,6,0.019875458),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.014933087,5,0.034681906),(3310,"1/15/2018",0.014448282,3,0.082049528)).toDF("id","date","revenue","con_dist_1","con_dist_2")

df.stat.approxQuantile(Array("con_dist_1", "con_dist_2"), Array(0.1, 0.5), 0)
```

Output (first dimension is column and second is the requested percentile, so for example, the 10th percentile of `con_dist_1` is 3.0):

```scala
Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(3.0, 4.0), Array(0.019875458, 0.034681906))
```

Comment: for which Spark version?